# VB6 Word Document collection contains manually opened docs

Tags: ms-word, vb6, word-2010

I'll try to explain my problem in steps, since i'm not sure how to describe it precisely.

1. I have a running VB6 process from the Visual Basic Editor
2. Word documents are getting created via Documents.Add like this:

   .Documents.Add Template:=NameOfTemplate
3. When I manually open a Word document, the Documents collection contains only the generated one.
4. The Word.Application object is a global variable

Now to the problem:

4. If I run the process from the binary, the Documents collection contains both - The generated doc and the manually opened doc.

How can I fix the behaviour so the Documents collection only contains generated docs from my code?

Comment: A little confusing but you seem to be talking about a difference between an IDE run and an EXE run.  If so, then all I can imagine is that the IDE is not running in the same user context as your compiled EXE.  Perhaps the IDE is elevated (as it should be) but the EXE is not being run elevated?  If so you are seeing expected behavior and there is nothing practical to be done about it.

Comment: Yes thats exactly it. If i run every instance with administrator rights both environments work the same. It's an application from 1992 i'm migrating to Windows 7 and Office 2010 =/.